# nodejs high cpu usage syscall

Tags: node.js, cpu-usage, profiler

I have `node` app that makes an excessive usage of CPU.
I have used the `--prof` option to profile cause.

The profiler indicate that:

- javascript uses 20% of all ticks
- c++ uses 67% of all ticks
- gc uses 8% of all ticks

[c++]: display 39% `syscall`
Diving into the c++ entry:

32.9% `v8::internal::Runtime_SetProperty(int, v8::internal::Object**,v8::internal::Isolate*)`

And 6.4% `handleApiCall`

I can't paste here the whole log, but I was wondering how can I understand and identify the root cause of the CPU usage from the log.